# Database setup for handling user activation via email laravel (5.3)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like some suggestions on the most efficient way for activating users via email. When users register I want an activation code to be created, which will be sent in an email to say they require activation, (activation code sent as domain url with token as parameter). However, I am not sure on what the best database structure for handling this would be...

The simple option, I presume, would be to have an `activation_token` and `activated` column in the `users` table, and when the url with matching user and `activation_token` is hit, `activated` will become true/!0. Although simple, I want to save as much space as possible on the users table.

Alternatively, I could make an `activation` table containing `user_id, token, activated` and create a one-to-one relationship between `users` and `activation`. In the `User` model have:

```
public function activation() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Activation');
}

public function activated() {
    return $this->activation->activated != 0 ? true:false;
}
```

Similarly, when the url with token parameter is hit for user, change `activated` to 1/true.

The activation links and registration confirmation are being pushed to a queue, so I am not overly concerned about the speed in which a user can become activated, but more on the length of additional time it will take to authenticate the user with the additional parameter requisite.

I'm sure there are probably better ways of doing this, but after googling user activation laravel 5.3 the results are generally outdated packages or tutorials for outdated methods and laravel versions. Alongside this, the available packages are not particularly lightweight and have numerous configuration settings which I simply don't need, and therefore do not want as I don't see the point in clogging when I can do this myself. I am also unwilling to trawl through someone else's package and remove unnecessary bulk (in the context of my needs).

So, can anyone please suggest a better alternative, or perhaps support one of the ideas above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the technique of sending activation link on user's email to activate one's account. As the answer would be a quite long, but I'll try to make it out as short as possible:

The users schema would look like this:

```
users
  - id
  - name
  - email
  - is_email_activated
  - activation_token
```

The controller would be like this (while creating the account of user):

```
class UsersController {

    function create() {
        $user = User::create(request()->all());

        $activation_token = $this->encryptData($user->id);
        $activation_link = route('verify_token', ['token' => $activation_token]);

        $user->activation_token = $activation_token;
        $user->save();

        // Send mail to user with activation link...
    }

    function encryptData($id, $delimiter='|', $expiry = 1) {
        $data[] = $id;
        $data[] = rand(0,999999);
        $data[] = time(); // This param can help us to retrieve the token generation time at the time of verification
        $key = implode($delimiter, $data);
        $key = Crypt::encrypt($key);
        return $key;
    }

}
```

Now the link sent to user's email should point to the route:

```
Route::get('users/activation/{token}', UsersController@verifyToken)->name('verify_token');
```

And the verification method would look like this:

```
class UsersController {

    function verifyToken($key) {
        $key = Crypt::decrypt($key);
        $data = explode("|", $key);
        $data['id'] = $data[0];
        $data['previous_time'] = $data[2];
        $data['success'] = true;

        $user = User::find($data['id'])

        // Token valid if user is found and token is valid for only 24 Hrs Check (not mandatory in case of email activation, you should use this in case of resetting user's password)
        if($user && (time() - ($data['previous_time'] <= 86400))) {
            // User validated and make is_email_activated column to true / 1
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!